# Find out the language of the user that filled in a form (Composite C1 forms renderer)

Tags: forms, c1-cms

We've got a form for a global datatype of our Composite C1 website that allows users to request a trial. This form is translated into German and English.
Now what we would need is to know what language-version of this form the users used to submit their request, so that we can send the German reply-mail to all germans, and the Englich reply-mail to all the others.

I would have thought of a hidden input element that is submitted along with the others. 
Anyways it would be great if this information was stored along with the other input from the user in our datatype, like for a german user "de" and the others "en"

Is there a way to achieve this using forms renderer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Form Builder](http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/Composite.Forms.FormBuilder) package which probably work a lot better in a multi lingual environment than the Form Renderer.

You can get this to work with the Form Renderer package by adding a string field to your data type, configure it to get a default value from a function you create (like a C# Function which return a string, based on CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) and then ensure your field do not have a widget. This will hide the field from the HTML form, but ensure it gets set with your default value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But how can I hide some field from the form? "ensure your field do not have a widget" - I don't know how that can be achieved... :/